# casting to unsigned char not working

Tags: c, types

I have a really irritating problem. This is the buffer structure i am using

```
typedef struct BufferDescriptor {
   char * ca_head ;    /* pointer to the beginning of character array (character buffer) */
   int capacity ;      /* current dynamic memory size (in bytes) allocated to character buffer */       
   char inc_factor;    /* character array increment factor */
   int addc_offset ;    /* the offset (in char elements) to the app-character location */
   int mark_offset ;   /* the offset (in chars elements) to the mark location */
   char r_flag;        /* reallocation flag */
   char mode;          /* operational mode indicator*/

} Buffer ;
```

I cannot make any changes to above code. The inc_factor is supposed to be able to take values from 0 to 255.

therefore in the function where a buffer is created, i do the following so as to ensure that the inc_factor is not negative:

```
Buffer* b_create(int init_capacity, char inc_factor,char o_mode){
    Buffer* buffer = (Buffer*)malloc(sizeof(Buffer));
    buffer->ca_head=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*init_capacity);

    buffer->inc_factor=(unsigned char)(inc_factor);
```

But the following line gives out a negative number:

```
printf("inc factor = %d",buffer->inc_factor);
```

What am I doing wrong here ? Plz Help.

Comment: Try: `(unsigned)buffer->inc_factor`

Comment: Hi Mystical, okay if i print with ur suggestion i get the right number. but the problem is that i want to make the correct assignment into the structure.
 buffer->inc_factor=(unsigned char)inc_factor; is not helping .. i am not sure why !
oh , is it that i will never be able to do that assignment? as buffer->inc_factor is defined to be a char ??

so, i will always need to cast it as (unsigned char)buffer->inc_factor to be able to use it ??

Thx!

Comment: `char` is apparently an 8-bit *signed* integer on your system. So you can't store anything larger than 127 or it will flip negative. But you can treat it as an unsigned value. But you'll need to cast it when you use it if you're not willing to change the struct to `unsigned char`.

Comment: Oops, I meant my first comment to be `(unsigned char)buffer->inc_factor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are formatting a `signed` variable as a `signed` value, so of course it will output a negative value if the variable exceeds 127. That is what happens when you store an `unsigned` value into a `signed` variable - it wraps around to the negative.  If you cannot change the variable type itself, then you have to change how it is being formatted (type-casting a `signed` value to an `unsigned` type and then assigning to a `signed` variable is pointless):

```
printf("inc factor = %u", (unsigned char) buffer->inc_factor);
```

Or:

```
printf("inc factor = %d", (unsigned char) buffer->inc_factor);
```

Comment: yes i see my folly now . was making a really foolish mistake ! Thanks Remy.

Comment: Hi Remy. I posted my answer before your answer appeared here so I didn't get a chance to take a look at it, sorry =( My question is, won't this read junk from memory, as you're passing a char (1 byte) and reading a decimal (4 or 8 bytes)?

Comment: Most function parameters take up 4 bytes of stack space in 32-bit machines, even if the data is only 1 byte in size.  Such a value would get extended up to 4 bytes when pushed onto the stack.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to cast wherever you want to *use* the value as `unsigned`.

```
char value = 255;
printf("%d\n", value);
printf("%d\n", (unsigned char) value);
```

Should output:

```
-1
255
```

Comment: Thanks pb2q! Yes, makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a type of a variable, you're actually telling the compiler how it should interpret the bits from memory. Therefore, casting a char into unsigned char doesn't change the bits in memory, but actually affects how the data affects the operations it is used in.

In your case, you cast it, but store back into a signed char. When the data is read by the compiler (remember, no bits are modified), it is interpreted as a signed char, because that is the type that of BufferDescriptor.inc_factor .

The simplest solution is to cast it when you use it:

```
printf("inc factor = %d",(unsigned char)buffer->inc_factor);
```

BUT there is serious and dangerous bug here. The compiler will push the arguments to the stack as they type it interprets (in this case, a single-byte unsigned char). The problem is that the printf function removes the parameter from the stack as they type you tell it to interpret (in this case, %d normally means a 4-byte integer). As you can see, there are 3 bytes that are missing. The printf will forcefully read those extra three bytes, so it will actually get invalid data from memory.

To fix this, push it to the stack as a 4-byte integer:

```
printf("inc factor = %d",(int)((unsigned char)buffer->inc_factor));
```

Notice that before we cast it to a 4-byte integer, we cast it as an unsigned char. This is to force the compiler to first interpret the bits as unsigned then to zero-extend (and not sign extend) the remaining 3-bytes.

Hope this helps =)

Answer (score 0):

In an 8 bit value of char, -1 = 1111 1111 in binary and 255 = 1111 1111 in binary.  So it's the same representation it all just depends on how you cast it.

If you don't cast printf("inc factor = %d",buffer->inc_factor); you will print -1 since %d is trying to print a signed decimal. If you cast the printing value like:

```
printf("inc factor = %d", (unsigned char) buffer->inc_factor);
```

you will print 255.  You should store a local variable as:

```
unsigned char unsigned_char_inc_factor = (unsigned char) buffer->inc_factor;
```

and just used unsigned_char_inc_factor afterwards.